# Assembler: What means RAM_SP+16H?

Tags: assembly, keil, machine-code

I need your help by this assembler code:

```
LOC  OBJ            LINE     SOURCE
0116               369     controll_time   EQU     RAM_SP+16H      ;enter controll time impulse
```

What does "RAM_SP+16H" means?

RAM_SP is the storage for C++ data an is equal 0100H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `RAM_SP+16H` refers to the address of `RAM_SP` plus 16 hexadecimal (or 22 decimal).  If `RAM_SP` has address `0100H`, this refers to the address `0116H`.

I suppose this is the address of the variable `controll_time`.